# Matlab Conditional Array Evaluation?

Tags: matlab, function, conditional-statements

I have a situation where I need to use a function to evaluate coefficients which are then multiplied by an array call and if the coefficient is evaluated to be 0 then I need a function or something that prevents that specific array call.

TL;DR

an example is like this:

```
   T(i,j)=Ce*T(i+1,j)
```

but I want to make it such that if Ce is equal to 0 then T(i+1,j) is never evaluated/called at all (in matlab).

Thanks so much for any reponses!

Answer (score 0):

From what your question relays, the simplest solution is using an `if` statement. Unless you want to do something else, that you need to explain more.

```
if Ce ~= 0; T(ii,jj) = Ce*T(ii+1,jj); end
```

example:

```
T = rand(3);
ii=2;
jj=2;
Ce = 0;
if Ce ~= 0 
    T(ii,jj) = Ce*T(ii+1,jj);
end
```